# Bash : Syntax error near unexpected token `elif' with if/then blocks w/ only comments

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax

I was putting comments on the if statements, just to be a placeholder, then I try to run it and ...
I got a syntax error :

> syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
>
> `elif [ $1 = "done" || $1 = "-d" ]; then'

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 = "add" || $1 = "-a"  ]]; then
  # statements
elif [[ $1 = "done" || $1 = "-d" ]]; then
  #statements
elif [[ $1 = "show" || $1 = "-s" ]]; then
  #statements
elif [[ $1 = "clear" || $1 = "-cl" ]]; then
  #statements
elif [[ $1 = "help" || $1 = "-h" ]]; then
  #statements
else
  showHelp
fi
```

**So what's really wrong here? Shouldn't this be valid?**

Comment: BTW, a `case` statement is better form here. That is: `case $1 in add|-a) ...;; done|-d) ... ;; show|-s) ... ;; *) showHelp ;; esac` -- that way your code will be compatible with all POSIX-compliant shells, and you don't need to keep repeating `$1` over and over.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy true, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: (As another aside -- the "snippet" mechanism is only for code that can be run in a browser -- "StackSnippets" are the local alternative to JSFiddle; use the `{}` button for general-purpose quoting and syntax highlighting of multi-line code blocks that aren't HTML/JavaScript. That said, this is a really great early contribution; the effort you've put in is obvious).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ah thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, bash thinks this is invalid. Turns out you cant have empty clauses as the error was really pointing to the first if statement because I didn't actually put anything inside it, just a placeholder.

I then checked [ShellCheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to see what's really going on and here it is :
[image: shellcheck]

To fix this, simply just put any block of code as the statements as the placeholder comments are invalid.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 = "add" || $1 = "-a" ]]; then
  echo add
elif [[ $1 = "done" || $1 = "-d" ]]; then
  echo done
elif [[ $1 = "show" || $1 = "-s" ]]; then
  echo show
elif [[ $1 = "clear" || $1 = "-cl" ]]; then
  echo clear
elif [[ $1 = "help" || $1 = "-h" ]]; then
  showHelp
else
  showHelp
fi
```

Comment: BTW, this isn't just bash -- if you wanted to extend this answer you could refer to the [POSIX sh standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html). Note that both valid forms of an `If` clause in the grammar start with `If compound_list Then`, and that all the possible derivations of `compound_list` contain at least one term.